# Way to detect if pointer points to a..., exactly where?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
char* cc = "Something string like";
char* ccn = new char[2];
ccn[0] = 'a';
ccn[1] = '\0';
cout << cc;
```

The second pointer, in order to prevent mem leak, should be `delete[]`'d but how can one detect if pointer actually points to new'd mem or not (like the one in first line)? And where is the first string created?

Comment: The first one should be either `const char* cc = ...` or `char cc[] = ...`.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't, and you shouldn't design your applications in a way that expects you to be able to do so.  Re your question about where the first string is created - the answer is "somewhere convenient for your compiler" - it is not specified by the C++ standard.

The obvious way round this problem is not to use arrays of char, but to use std::strings.

Comment: Well, technically you could, but that would only give you the knowledge for that specific plattform and that specific compiler and that specific compiler version, so I'm not gonna elaborate on this, as it's pretty much *bad*.

Comment: @Xeo actually, even for a specific platform it is fraught with problems. This is discussed at some length in Effective C++.

Answer (score 0):

In standard C++, there is no way to know from a raw pointer alone, how the associated resources (if any) were allocated.

You could perhaps use smart pointers instead, since they pass resource ownership information along with the raw pointer value. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct noop_deleter {
    void operator()(T *p) {}
};

boost::shared_array<const char> cc("Something string like", noop_deleter<char>());
boost::shared_array<char> ccn(new char[2]);

ccn[0] = 'a';
ccn[1] = 0;
cout << cc.get();
```